# What kind of transformation is that?

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, rotations, reflection

We have the glide reflection
\begin{equation*}\kappa \begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x+2\\ -y+2\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}
and the rotation
\begin{equation*}\delta \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -x +2\\ -y+2\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}
The composition of these maps is
$$\kappa\circ\delta\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}= \kappa \left (\delta \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}\right )=\kappa \begin{pmatrix} -x +2\\ -y+2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -x +4\\ -y+4\end{pmatrix}$$
What kind of transformation is that?

Comment: What do you think? If you consider specific points, where do they seem to go? Is this orientation preserving or not?

Comment: What do you think about point $(2,2)$ ?

Comment: Your final expression for $\kappa \circ \delta$ is wrong. The map $\kappa$ maps $-y+2$ to $-(-y+2)+2 = y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment, the right map is
$$(\kappa \circ \delta)(x,y) = (-x+4,y).$$
Note that you can write $(\kappa \circ \delta)(x,y) = (-x,y)+(4,0)$, or equivalently using matrices
$$(\kappa \circ \delta) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y
\end{matrix}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y
\end{matrix}
\right)+
\left(
\begin{matrix}
4 \\
0
\end{matrix}
\right)
= A
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y
\end{matrix}
\right)
+ b.
$$
So $\kappa \circ \delta$ îs an affine transformation of $\mathbb R^2$ and is a composition of an improper ($\det A = -1$) rotation $A \in \mathrm{O}(2)$ and a translation by a vector $b = (4,0)$ (horizontal translation in positive direction). The transformation fixes the line given by points $(2,y)$, because $(\kappa \circ \delta)(2,y) = (2,y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: How do we know that this fixed point is unique?

Comment: Sorry, I based my last sentence on zwim's comment and your expression for the map. There is not only one point that is fixed, but a whole line. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)